# How to add query parameters using Jetty HttpClient

Tags: java, http, jetty, jetty-9

how can I pass parameters in the URL using Jetty 9 client Request?
I tried the following but it did not work:

```
String url= http://localhost/myApp    
Request request = httpClient.newRequest(url);
request.param("param","value");
```

I want to add parameters in the URL to be like the following when I send my request:

```
http://localhost/myApp?param=value
```

Comment: What if you add your params after question mark right into URL string?

Comment: Your code works as is.

Comment: if I add my params after the question mark it works, but I want to use the "request.param()" function, can't see why it is not working :(

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt: thanks, the code is working as it is! My problem was a wrong value in the parameter -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is working as it is! My problem was a wrong value in the parameter.